# Menus are not showing on desktop display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting **state= false** on desktop size when there is no toggle option as it is defined as false initially. Because of this, no menus are showing. I want this functionality only when the website is opened on mobile, not on desktop.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkIfClickedOutside = (e) => {
      if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target)) {
        setIsMenuOpen(false);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
    };

  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <nav>
          <div className="nav">
            <div className="nav-brand">
              <Link to="./" className="text-black">
                Website
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div ref={ref}> // <-- ref to this containing div
              <div className="toggle-icon" onClick={toggle}>
                <i
                  id="toggle-button"
                  className={isMenuOpen ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"}
                />
              </div>
              {isMenuOpen && (
                <div className={isMenuOpen ? "nav-menu visible" : "nav-menu"}>
                  ....
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit morning-leftpad-4mgs2n]

Comment: So is it specifically this `isMenuOpen` state being initially false by default that is the issue? What are you using to determine if code is running in a mobile vs larger desktop view? You could apply some logic to compute the initial state, i.e. something like `const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(!isMobile);`

Comment: I am just changing the browser width size to check the website's responsiveness.

Comment: IIRC you were using some bootstrap CSS. Can you create a running codesandbox demo of your code that we can inspect live?

Comment: I have added code sandbox link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an initial state value that checks if the window's width is greater than your mobile media query size.

```
* Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  /* -------------Bottom Header------------- */
  .....
}
```

Example:

```
const isMobile = window.innerWidth <= 767.98;

export default function App() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(!isMobile);
  const toggle = () => isMobile && setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);

  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMobile) {
      const checkIfClickedOutside = (e) => {
        if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target)) {
          setIsMenuOpen(false);
        }
      };
    
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
    
      return () => {
        // Cleanup the event listener
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return ( .... );
}
```

[image: Edit menus-are-not-showing-on-desktop-display]

This, OFC, assumes that the app's viewport is static. If you need a dynamic response then use an `useEffect` hook to add an `onResize` event handler to the `window` object.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const resizeHandler = () => {
    ... logic to get window size and handle setting the menu state
  };

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
  };
}, []);
```